# Flutter crashes on iOS due to failing construction of a thread

Tags: ios, multithreading, flutter

I just wanted to debug some changes I made in my Flutter app on iOS. Started it from VS Code and received the following error:

```
libc++abi: terminating with uncaught exception of type std::__1::system_error: thread constructor failed: Resource temporarily unavailable
* thread #1, queue = 'com.apple.main-thread', stop reason = signal SIGABRT
    frame #0: 0x00000001b928e964 libsystem_kernel.dylib`__pthread_kill + 8
libsystem_kernel.dylib`__pthread_kill:
->  0x1b928e964 <+8>:  b.lo   0x1b928e984               ; <+40>
    0x1b928e968 <+12>: pacibsp 
    0x1b928e96c <+16>: stp    x29, x30, [sp, #-0x10]!
    0x1b928e970 <+20>: mov    x29, sp
Target 0: (Runner) stopped.
```

As far as I understand and what I found on the internet, the application fails to create a thread. Unfortunately, it does not tell much about why this happens or who is trying to create the thread.

I tried multiple things to reduce the causing possibilities:

- used Simulator
- used real device
- `flutter clean`
- restarted VS Code
- restarted Mac
- rolled back my code changes
- install on device instead of debug

None of it changes anything. Error still occurs. Didn't had the chance to run it from another Mac.

Does anybody know the error or has a tip of what to do?

`flutter doctor -v`:

```
[✓] Flutter (Channel stable, 2.5.3, on macOS 12.0.1 21A559 darwin-arm, locale en-DE)
    • Flutter version 2.5.3 at /Users/****/tools/flutter
    • Upstream repository https://github.com/flutter/flutter.git
    • Framework revision 18116933e7 (5 weeks ago), 2021-10-15 10:46:35 -0700
    • Engine revision d3ea636dc5
    • Dart version 2.14.4

[✓] Android toolchain - develop for Android devices (Android SDK version 31.0.0)
    • Android SDK at /Users/****/Library/Android/sdk
    • Platform android-31, build-tools 31.0.0
    • Java binary at: /Applications/Android Studio.app/Contents/jre/Contents/Home/bin/java
    • Java version OpenJDK Runtime Environment (build 11.0.10+0-b96-7249189)
    • All Android licenses accepted.

[✓] Xcode - develop for iOS and macOS
    • Xcode at /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer
    • Xcode 13.1, Build version 13A1030d
    • CocoaPods version 1.11.2

[✓] Chrome - develop for the web
    • Chrome at /Applications/Google Chrome.app/Contents/MacOS/Google Chrome

[✓] Android Studio (version 2020.3)
    • Android Studio at /Applications/Android Studio.app/Contents
    • Flutter plugin can be installed from:
       https://plugins.jetbrains.com/plugin/9212-flutter
    • Dart plugin can be installed from:
       https://plugins.jetbrains.com/plugin/6351-dart
    • Java version OpenJDK Runtime Environment (build 11.0.10+0-b96-7249189)

[✓] VS Code (version 1.62.3)
    • VS Code at /Applications/Visual Studio Code.app/Contents
    • Flutter extension version 3.28.0

[✓] Connected device (3 available)
    • MyRealDevice (mobile) • 00008030-0001359001******            • ios            • iOS 15.1 19B74
    • iPhone 13 (mobile)  • 1D5FF828-1E37-4E2B-88E8-B2010FC5DB3E • ios            • com.apple.CoreSimulator.SimRuntime.iOS-15-0 (simulator)
    • Chrome (web)        • chrome                               • web-javascript • Google Chrome 96.0.4664.55

• No issues found!
```

Answer (score 0):

Solved it by checking the latest changes in git. After reversing the following line in the file `Info.plist`

```
    <key>UILaunchStoryboardName</key>
    <string>Main</string>
```

to

```
    <key>UILaunchStoryboardName</key>
    <string>LaunchScreen</string>
```

I still don't understand why this caused the error but now it's gone.